# Automapper. Not obvious transformation

Tags: entity, automapper, transformation, dto

I have the following scenario:

```
public class SourceEntity
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string ClientMultipleValues1 { get; set; }
    public string ClientMultipleValues2 { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationDto
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public List<string> list1 { get; set; }
    public List<string> list2 { get; set; }
}
```

SourceEntity values:

```
ClientId|ClientName|ClientMultipleValues1 |ClientMultipleValues2                       
   1    |  Albert  |       aaaaa          |       bbbbbbb  
   1    |  Albert  |       ccccc          |       ddddddd  
   2    |  Roger   |       zzzzz          |       yyyyyyy
```

I want using automapper that DestinationDto has these values:

```
ClientId|ClientName|     list1      |      list2
   1    |  Albert  |{ aaaaa, ccccc }|{ bbbbbbb, ddddddd }
   2    |  Roger   |{ zzzzz }       |{ yyyyyyy }
```

Is it possible to do it? I mean, ClientId and ClientName must have only one row and ClientMultipleValues1, ClientMultipleValues2 have to be transformed into a List to make it possible.

Thanks

Comment: This is not mapping? This is aggregating more than one objects into one object, as far as I understand?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but not with Automapper.  As @huzeyfe noted, you're looking for aggregation, not mapping.  A Linq statement will be able to do this for you.  Look into GroupBy method (assuming you're going to group on ClientId).  Then project into the DestinationDto.